# App.configuration namespace

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Where can i find this namespace? App.configuration

```
App.Configuration.UrlCapture.Cert = 
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", null);
```

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jul/29/Using-FiddlerCore-to-capture-HTTP-Requests-with-NET

I was leading about fiddler core and chanced upon this code but is unable to find the App.Configuration namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that this is a custom property on his App class... in fact a bit of bingling finds the code in [GitHub](https://github.com/RickStrahl/WestWindWebSurge/blob/ec912e4e72ff77ba051b51a361c3a9ba0fc9bfc8/WebSurge/FiddlerCapture.cs). Particularly the [WebSurgeConfiguration class](https://github.com/RickStrahl/WestWindWebSurge/blob/964a46ff8dd27654713c3415e38b09cc2f24fb6b/WebSurge.Core/Configuration/WebSurgeConfiguration.cs)

I think you'll find all the answers in that Repo :)